# Ember error route doesn't call model

Tags: ember.js, error-handling, routes

In [Ember documentation](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates/#toc_code-error-code-substates) it says that when model's promise gets rejected Ember will search for ErrorRoute and pass error message of rejected promise to ErrorRoute's model.

The problem is, ErrorRoute's model never gets called. ( the route itself initializes )

I can see failed promises with error message flying around in [ember inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mz4zT.png), but it never reaches the model.

[demo on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/qexaj/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says it will apply the model for you, not hit the model hook.  But for some reason, if the failure isn't an object(as a usual thrown error should be) it won't get applied as the model.

```
Ember.RSVP.reject({foo:"bad things!"});
```

http://jsbin.com/gicekajo/1/edit